# Logging to a file in golang

Tags: go

I am starting out with golang, and as I am starting to build out my applciation I want to add logging from the start, and that is where I am running into issues.

If I open a file and use the standard logging library, I am able to write to a file.  Like so.

```
    package main



   import (
        "os"
        "fmt"
        "log"
    )


    func main() {
        // open a file
        f, err := os.OpenFile("test.log", os.O_APPEND | os.O_CREATE | os.O_RDWR, 0666)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("error opening file: %v", err)
        }

        // don't forget to close it
        defer f.Close()

        // assign it to the standard logger
        log.SetOutput(f)

        log.Output(1, "this is an event")

    }
```

I will get my test.log with the log line in it.  However if I try to adapt this to support logrus https://github.com/Sirupsen/logrus like this

```
    package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    log "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
)

func init() {

    // open a file
    f, err := os.OpenFile("testlogrus.log", os.O_APPEND | os.O_CREATE | os.O_RDWR, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error opening file: %v", err)
    }

    // don't forget to close it
    defer f.Close()

    // Log as JSON instead of the default ASCII formatter.
    log.SetFormatter(&log.JSONFormatter{})

    // Output to stderr instead of stdout, could also be a file.
    log.SetOutput(f)

    // Only log the warning severity or above.
    log.SetLevel(log.DebugLevel)
}


func main() {

    log.WithFields(log.Fields{
        "Animal": "Logrus",
    }).Info("A logrus appears")


}
```

All I will ever see are errors.

Failed to write to log, write testlogrus.log: bad file descriptor

All I ever get is the bad file descriptor error.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks
Craig

Comment: Also look at https://github.com/natefinch/lumberjack

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you setup the file in the `init` function and you have `defer f.Close()`, the file gets closed after `init` returns.

you either have to keep the file open or move the whole thing into main.

Comment: Nice!  That's it.  Would the best practice in go be to move my logging initialization from init to main, or to just keep the log file open without the explicit close?

Comment: @Craig I'd just just move it to main, because if you don't close it on exit you can be miss few bytes at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux
In development you can write to stdout and pipe to a file.
In production write to syslog.
Both ways you dont need to handle the file yourself.

Comment: s/Linux/unix-like/g or better yet `s/Linux/sane OS/g`

Comment: Is it good idea to create log file in /var/log/myAppLog.log for production ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use logrus you should better use hooks which is recommended by documentation.

See : https://github.com/rifflock/lfshook for examples.

In my opinon moving the whole thing to the main is generally not a good idea, instead we want well-segmented code.