# Why is the native Golang logger not logging when it's a global variable?

Tags: logging, go

I have some pretty simple code where I'm logging some error info to a file.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

var testLogger *log.Logger

func init() {
    logFile, openErr1 := os.OpenFile("/home/doug/logs/test.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND, 0666)

    if openErr1 != nil {
        log.Println("Uh oh! Could not open log file.")
    }

    defer logFile.Close()

    testLogger = log.New(logFile, "PREFIX", log.Lshortfile|log.Ldate|log.Ltime)
}

func main() {
    testLogger.Println("meep meep")
}
```

However, whenever I open the file after running the program, it is always empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: doesn't the `defer logFile.Close()` run at the end of the init function? Doesn't that mean you're closing the file out from under the logger?

Comment: @ChrisTavares GAH. So I should run that in `main()` then?

Comment: @DougSmith  putting the defer in main and leaving the rest won't work; moving all of your log config to the top of main works... such as is suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619318/logging-to-a-file-in-golang

Comment: You could just leave the close out completely - it's not a file leak since you WANT the file open for the length of the process. When the process exits the file will get closed automatically by the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Doug already pointed out, the `init()` function will always be invoked before `main()`, and sequentially so. That means that when `init()` finishes, the queued up `defer`s within `init()` will execute, in this case closing your log.

In most cases, you are not meant to call `log.Close()` at all. Note that all `Fatal` functions on `log` will `os.Exit`:

https://golang.org/src/log/log.go?s=9087:9131#L295

And docs on `os.Exit` explicitly say `defer`s are not run

```
// Exit causes the current program to exit with the given status code.
// Conventionally, code zero indicates success, non-zero an error.
// The program terminates immediately; deferred functions are not run.
func Exit(code int) {
```

Therefore, you might say the standard lib forces you to not `log.Close()` in case of a fatal error. Kind of suggests it's not a big deal.

Note that `Panic` functions, however, will run `defer`red functions before exiting.